# How do i find top row visible on Sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

I searched and found many solutions to get first "visible" row as a row which is not hidden but that is NOT what is required.

I am looking for simply the row on top of screen currently.

For example if row user scrolls down until row 30 is on top, I wish to use vba to get the top row which is row 30.

Any help / guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [window.visiblerange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.visiblerange)  From that you can get `.Rows(1)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen post as answer for me to accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Visible" area of Excel can be accessed via a `Window` and it's `VisibleRange` property.

The `ActiveWindow` may give you what you want, but be aware that if you have more than one workbook open, and or more than one view open on a workbook, `ActiveWindow` may not give you the window you expect.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim wnd As Window
    Dim WindowRange As Range
    Dim WindowTopRow As Range
    
    ' Get reference to required window
    Set wnd = ActiveWindow ' or by another method
    ' Get Reference to whole visible range
    Set WindowRange = wnd.VisibleRange
    ' Get Reference to top row
    Set WindowTopRow = WindowRange.Rows(1)
    
    ' Report findings
    Debug.Print "Window", wnd.Caption
    Debug.Print "Visible Range", WindowRange.Address(, , , True)
    Debug.Print "Top Row", WindowTopRow.Row
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
? Activewindow.VisibleRange.Row
```